# Whats the difference between "Type Certificate" and "Type Certificate Data Sheet" and how it fits into airworthiness

Tags: faa-regulations, airworthiness

From my knowledge, a type certificate is given to the manufacturer which in turn allows them to get an airworthiness certificate for the plane it manufactures without having to go back to the FAA to ask for it. I know the TCDS outlines the general information about the design and assigns specific numbers to it. That is about all I know about TCDS though. If anyone can tell me more about the two and how they relate to each other and airworthiness it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [FAA Order 8110.4C - "Type Certification"](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FAA_Order_8110_4C_Chg_6.pdf) fully explains the entire aircraft certification process (TC, TCDS, Airworthiness Certficate, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

The Certificate Data Sheet is a component of the "Type Certificate"

> § [21.41 Type certificate.](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/section-21.41)
>
> Each type certificate is considered to include the type design, the
> operating limitations, the certificate data sheet, the applicable
> regulations of this subchapter with which the FAA records compliance,
> and any other conditions or limitations prescribed for the product in
> this subchapter.

In other words if Boeing holds the Type Certificate for the 737 they hold all the above listed documents including the Certificate Data Sheet, this in turn allows them to apply for ["Production Under Type Certificate"](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/production_approvals/prod_under_tc) to actually build the airplane. If you want to see whats included in the TCDS, they are public and [you can check them out here for your favorite airframes.](https://drs.faa.gov/browse/TCDSMODEL/doctypeDetails)